# A non-descript cryptic clue

Tags: cryptic-clues, crossword-clues

Couldn't find the following cryptic clue on Puzzling, I've been told it's one of the very best:

> ? (1, 5'1, 3, 1, 4)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer might be:

> I HAVEN'T GOT A CLUE.

Because

> Quite literally there's no clue.

Comment: I'll wait for any other answers over the next 24 hours, but it looks like yours might be right.

Comment: @boboquack: I can confirm that that's correct.

Comment: @Desuvoi do you know where it came from?

Comment: @boboquack: Unfortunately not. I've seen the same clue for "CLUELESS", though.